# How to wrap the breadcrumb text in new line when the width of pop up overflows without using scroll?

Tags: html, css, angular

Currently, I have scrollable wrap of the breadcrumb with text overflow[image: Actual UX]
And I wanted to add the overflowed text to next line how can I add it?
CSS which i am using for attached image is

```
.breadcrumb-css {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    width: 8em;
    word-break: break-all;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

The UX which I am looking for is as below

[image: Expected UX]

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-and-material-multi-level-menu-with-breadc-9mt3ut?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Please also add the code of the part where all the breadcrumbs are in together

Comment: Please have a  look into below stackblitz
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-and-material-multi-level-menu-with-breadc-9mt3ut?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your app.component.html add new css to `mat-toolbar` here is css `flex-wrap: wrap;height:auto;` and that will do the work.